# Ansible print remote config locally

Tags: ansible, config

I'm attempting to use Ansible to to find a similar setting with different values on multiple servers then output that locally on my system via a CSV.  The issue is Ansible will only output one line to the file even though it found and assembled and even says it created two lines from each server.

So, example setup:

```
Server1
file.conf
key=value1

Server2
file.conf
key=value2

Local
result.txt
```

```yaml
---
# ansible-playbook pb-get-file.yml -i inventory --limit=server1,server2
- name: Playbook to get a list of all file values
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Find the status and targetUri of the nested DS Served
    find:
      paths: 
        - /opt/
        - /etc/
      recurse: yes
      contains: '.*key.*'
      patterns: '*file.conf'
    register: ds_status
    become: yes
  
  - name: Get values
    shell:
      cmd: "awk '/key/{print $NF}' {{ item.path }}"
    register: r
    with_items: "{{ ds_status.files }}"
    become: yes
    when: ds_status.matched > 0

  - name: Save results
    lineinfile:
      line: "{{ item.0 }}, {{ item.1.path }}, {{ item.2.stdout }}"
      path: result.txt
      create: yes
    with_items: "{{ result_line }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    with_together:
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      - "{{ ds_status.files }}"
      - "{{ r.results }}" 
    when: ds_status.matched > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run_once` and `loop` *ansible_play_hosts_all* in the task "Save results". For example, given the files

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /opt/file.conf
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3

shell> ssh admin@test_12 cat /opt/file.conf
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3

shell> ssh admin@test_13 cat /opt/file.conf
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

Your playbook with the modified task below

```yaml
    - name: Save results
      debug:
        msg: |
          {{ item }},
          {{ hostvars[item].r.results.0.item.path }},
          {{ hostvars[item].r.results.0.stdout }}
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_11 -> localhost] => (item=test_11) => 
  msg: |-
    test_11,
    /opt/file.conf,
    key1=value1
    key2=value2
    key3=value3
ok: [test_11 -> localhost] => (item=test_12) => 
  msg: |-
    test_12,
    /opt/file.conf,
    key1=value1
    key2=value2
    key3=value3
ok: [test_11 -> localhost] => (item=test_13) => 
  msg: |-
    test_13,
    /opt/file.conf,
    key1=value1
    key2=value2
    key3=value3
```

Only one file per remote host is displayed in the loop. To save all files in the loop `include_tasks` with the next iteration.